# Is "lose" correct in this context?

Tags: grammaticality

> The system must be recoverable to protect data from any lose.

I don't know if it is grammatically correct; in particular, I don't know if *lose* is correct, or what I should use instead of it.

Comment: As with some of OP's earlier questions, I think this is part of a salami-style proofreading exercise.

Comment: @FumbleFingers did you just coin a new phrase? I cannot find 'salami style proofreading' on google.

Comment: @EnglishLearner: I've no idea whether anyone has ever specifically referred to *'salami style proofreading'* before, but the basic concept of [salami tactics, also known as the salami-slice strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salami_tactics) is pretty well-known. In this case what I mean, obviously, is that the OP is giving us his draft technical specification document line-by-line, since if he posted the entire text in one question, it would just get closed straight away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Lose* is a verb, not a noun; you should use *loss*.

> the state of no longer having something or as much of something; the process that leads to this

I would rather rewrite the sentence as follows:

> The System must be recoverable to avoid any data loss.